# Why are my anchor tags don't move to div targets?

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem with my portfolio site in regards to the anchor tags that I set on the arrow icons. It seems that the first arrow I set up on the splash screen moves to the next section. The other two arrows I setup do not move to next section/div on the page. I'm not sure what is causing this to happen as I've setup id's for the divs I will be referring to in the anchor tags of the second and third buttons.

Arrow 2

```
  <div id="snap" class="bounce arrow">
            <a href="#featproject">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </div>


            <!-- Carousel of Projects -->
        <div class="row featuredprojects" id="featproject">

         <div class="col-md-12">
           <h2><u>Featured Projects</u></h2>
         </div>

        </div>
```

Arrow 3

```
<div id="snap" class="bounce arrow">
          <a href="#contact">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
 </div>

<div class="contact" id="contact">

    <button id="contact_button" class="unstyled-button contact-button" data-modal-type="modal-8" >Contact</button>

</div>
```

Style.css

```
       * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        }

        html,body
        {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        body {
        background-color: #fafaf6; /* #fafaf6 */
        color: black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        header {
        height: 100vh;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: url("../img/splashscreen.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        }

        .header-container{
        padding-right: 110px;
        padding-left: 220px;
        color: #40E0D0;
        }

        .arrow{
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .bio{
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        }

        .bio-section{
        height: 100vh;
        }

        .featuredprojects{
        background-image: url("../img/coding.jpg");
        height: 100vh;
        color: #40E0D0;

        }

        .contact{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #40E0D0;
        }
```

Note: Sorry for the indentation, this is my first time actually posting on StackOverflow. I edited comments that are not necessary to the code. I refactored the splash screen in my code which i put in a header tag and noticed that is when those buttons broke. I've included my GitHub below.

GitHub: https://github.com/adamdevelops/adamdevelops.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by removing html,body and body style property for x-overflow and y-overflow. After doing so, the anchor tag buttons move to the next div with specific id.

Comment: Forgot to add the answer for this when I resolved it. Will make a video on this issue when I can.